# Logically equivalent Through expressions, but one produces an error

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a list of three lists of strings. Thus, `MatchQ[{{__String}, {__String}, {__String}}]` is `True`. I would like to extract all the strings which are present in the first two lists but not in the third.

According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html), the following two expressions using `Through` should be logically equivalent. Yet, the first one runs without error, while the second one produces the message shown below, before producing the correct output anyway:

```
ClearAll[lst];
lst = {CharacterRange["a", "h"], CharacterRange["d", "k"], CharacterRange["g", "n"]};

lst // Through[{Most /* Apply[Intersection], Last}[#]] & // Apply[Complement]
(* Output: {d, e, f} *)

lst // Through[Complement[Most /* Apply[Intersection], Last][#]] &
(*
    Complement::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in Complement[Most/*Apply[Intersection],Last].
    {d, e, f}
*)
```

Why is the second expression generating an error message?

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as the first expression (which does not produce an error)? The operator `@@` is the same as `Apply`. I am trying to understand why the second one would produce an error message, since the documentation suggests that I should be able to apply the head `Complement` in `Through` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through) does not have any [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold) attributes:

```
Attributes[Through]
```

> {Protected}

Hence, [`Complement`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement) tries to evaluate before [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through) performs its function. For a simpler example:

```
Through[Complement[Most, Rest][Range[10]]]
```

> Complement::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Complement[Most,Rest].
>
> {1}

Since `Complement[Most, Rest]` doesn't evaluate, [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through) will still do its thing, and then [`Complement`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement) will evaluate. Another way of seeing this is to give [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through) the [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll) attribute:

```
SetAttributes[Through, HoldAll]
Through[Complement[Most, Rest][Range[10]]]
ClearAttributes[Through, HoldAll]
```

> {1}

No error messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: Is there any conceivable benefit to not having this as the default setting? Why would the designers have chosen not to give `Through` the `HoldAll` attribute?